# Android ScrollView With Clickable TextViews

Tags: android, intellij-idea, scrollview

I am currently dealing with the design of an application, and I'm stuck with ways how to do it. My app needs a portion where the user reads a particular information.

My design goes like this:

**I. INTRODUCTION**

1. part 1
2. part 2

**II. SECOND TOPICS**

1. part a
2. part b

**part 1**

details here - long explanation

**part 2**

details here - long explanation

(continuation)

The numbered parts are clickable, therefore has a function to go to a certain part in the scroll view. (e.g. when 1. part 1 is clicked, it will go to the portion of 1. part 1 with details in the same scroll view) this is actually like the one being seen in some apps.

Additionally, when a user doesn't click the clickable items, the user can scroll down all the information written. And I am planning to have a separate button aside from back button that will go to the top portion or the clickable items if the user wants to, when already reached a far section of the information.

Formerly, i'm using an absolute layout for this one, in IntelliJ 12, but I've read some forums that it is a no no to use absolute layout and it is not compatible with a scroll view. So i changed to linear layout even though i already cannot set the x and y coordinates which i liked with the absolute layout.

Am I on the right track with my codes? Or there is an other way around to do this?

This is my code in the XML part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ffffff">


<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="330dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" android:layout_gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/white_paper_complete">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txt_space" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="26dp"
                android:text="I. INTRODUCTION"
                android:id="@+id/textView" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16dp" android:layout_y="19dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="              1. Tax Payer"
                android:id="@+id/textView1" android:clickable="true" android:layout_x="55dp" android:layout_y="44dp"
                android:linksClickable="false" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_gravity="center|left"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="              2. Tax Identification Number (TIN)"
                  android:id="@+id/textView2" android:clickable="true" android:layout_x="55dp" android:layout_y="64dp"
                  android:linksClickable="false" android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="              3. National Internal Revenue Code" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:clickable="true"
                  android:layout_x="55dp" android:layout_y="84dp" android:linksClickable="false"
                  android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="              4. Republic Act No. 8424" android:id="@+id/textView4" android:clickable="true"
                  android:layout_x="55dp" android:layout_y="104dp" android:linksClickable="false"
                  android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="              5. Bureau of Internal Revenue (BIR)" android:id="@+id/textView5" android:clickable="true"
                  android:layout_x="55dp" android:layout_y="124dp" android:linksClickable="false"
                  android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/textView14" android:clickable="true" android:layout_x="55dp"
                  android:layout_y="235dp" android:linksClickable="false" android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="           II. INCOME TAX IN THE PHILIPPINES" android:id="@+id/textView6" android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textSize="16dp" android:layout_x="40dp"
                  android:layout_y="150dp"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="              1. Income Tax"
                  android:id="@+id/textView7" android:clickable="true" android:layout_x="55dp" android:layout_y="175dp"
                  android:linksClickable="false" android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="              2.Taxable Income"
                  android:id="@+id/textView8" android:clickable="true" android:layout_x="55dp" android:layout_y="195dp"
                  android:linksClickable="false" android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="              3.Who are exempted from Income Tax?" android:id="@+id/textView9" android:clickable="true"
                  android:layout_x="55dp" android:layout_y="215dp" android:linksClickable="false"
                  android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="              4. How are Income Taxes being paid?" android:id="@+id/textView10"
                  android:clickable="true" android:layout_x="55dp" android:layout_y="235dp"
                  android:linksClickable="false" android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="              5. Income Tax Return (ITR)" android:id="@+id/textView12"
                  android:clickable="true" android:layout_x="55dp" android:layout_y="235dp"
                  android:linksClickable="false" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="              6 Who are required to file ITR" android:id="@+id/textView13"
                  android:clickable="true" android:layout_x="55dp" android:layout_y="235dp"
                  android:linksClickable="false" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                />
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/textView11"
                  android:clickable="true" android:layout_x="55dp" android:layout_y="235dp"
                  android:linksClickable="false" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Back"
        android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/black_btn"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my code for its class:

```
public class Tutorial extends MyActivity
{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial_design);

    TextView a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_about) ;
   final TextView b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_info) ;
    TextView c = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_calcu) ;
    TextView e = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_exit) ;

   final ScrollView x = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

    a.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
                //int location_x[] = new int[85];
               //int location_y[] = new int[200];

                //x.getLocationOnScreen(location_x);
           x.scrollTo(85,10000);


        }
    });
}


}
```

Help me please. :( Any help will be APPRECIATED! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not what you're looking for, but you should be better off using single HTML document with links like `<a href="#part1">`?

Then, you display the HTML in a WebView and you will have both clickable links and scrollable text.

Comment: Oh thanks! But how can I set the scroll view in a particular part when a text view was clicked?

Comment: you don't need to! it will scroll because it is a hyperlink and the WebView scrolls by itself :)

Comment: I guess you're a heaven sent! Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 1):

See if you use `requestRectangleOnScreen(rectangle)` or `requestFocus()`  methods of View.

For example :
If clicks of
Topic 1. And you know content of topic are shown by certain topicOneTextView or any view for that matter.
Then try calling

```
topicTextView.requestRectangleOnScreen(rectangle)
```

This will scroll if necessary.

Hope this helps

Comment: umm I you may need to do that.

Comment: Hmm regarding with this approach, do I need a separate View for each detailed explanation? @Changdeo Jadhav